# IIS / web.config url redirect rule based on regex is not triggered

Tags: asp.net, regex, redirect, iis, web-config

Here is my web.config rule

```
    <rule name="spiderRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".post/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.net/bot/post.php?category={toLower:{R:1}}&amp;id={toLower:{R:2}}&amp;title={toLower:{R:3}}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

This should give this result

input:

https://example.net/post/celebrity/4cHYQ7i/maisie-williams

should result in:

```
{R1}: celebrity
{R2}: 4cHYQ7i
{R3}: maisie-williams
```

and it should redirect to:

https://example.net/bot/post.php?category=celebrity&id=4cHYQ7i&title=maisie-williams

This input:

https://example.net/post/nerdy/NE5cHQZ/when-i-have-to-do-technical-support

should result in:

```
{R1}: nerdy
{R2}: NE5cHQZ
{R3}: when-i-have-to-do-technical-support
```

The server runs and I am quite sure the regex is correct, but the rule is never triggered. I am never redirected to google, even if I use the above input.

Why isn't the rule triggered?

Comment: Why does your regex have a leading dot?

Comment: Also you should use the `^$` anchors in your regex to avoid incorrect captures.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Also with check for User agent. 
I use this to redirect web crawlers.

```
    <rule name="spiderRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".?post/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(Google|MSNBot|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Facebot|facebookexternalhit|MJ12bot|bingbot|SimplePie|SiteLockSpider|okhttp|curl|YandexBot|ScoutJet|Slurp|DuckDuckBot|Baiduspider|Sogou|Konqueror|Exabot|ia_archiver|Screaming)"/>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.net/bot/post.php?category={toLower:{R:1}}&amp;id={toLower:{R:2}}&amp;title={toLower:{R:3}}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will escape "/" to matching your different input. The new regex is :

```
([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)
```

You can test it on https://regex101.com.
It match for your two different input.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to: <match url="post\/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)" />, but it still does not trigger a match..

Comment: Your regex doesn't match for your two input? I think the problem come from 'post'

Comment: @Mattlasse I does check out at regex101. I have to indicate that I want the values after 'post'